# Search Implementation for Endless Scrolling in Android

Tags: android

I fetch data from mysql server using async task loaders by the technique of endless scrolling. 
Using onQueryTextChange i can only implement search on the data that has been fetched . 
I want that all the data i can implement search for all the data that is present on database without disturbing endless scrolling.[Code of onQueryTextChange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kceuX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start an async task to fetch suggestion from the server and populate your `dataList` in OnPostComplete method and set the data as the suggestion instead of setting it in `onQueryChange`